# android facebook integration: invalid key hash

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, hash

The Facebook error message is :
Invalid key hash. The key hash xxxxxxx= does not match any stored key hashes...

I know this issue has been already treated but i still have the problem. I wrote below the detailled process but i should have miss something. Please help.

I am working on windows 10/Cordova/android.

1. Open cmd window as adminstrator
2. npm update -g cordova
3. cordova platform update android
4. cd  platforms\android\build\outputs\apk; rm *.apk
5. keytool -genkey -v -keystore myapp.keystore -alias myappalias-keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
6. cordova build android –release
7. Create platforms\android\release-signing.properties file including:

   ```
   storeType=jks
   keyAlias=myappalias
   keyPassword=mypass
   storePassword=mypass
   ```
8. remove the app from the android-smartphone
9. cordova run android –release

The key hash i cut& paste in the facebook field is given by the command:

```
keytool -exportcert -list -v -alias myappalias -keystore myapp.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

It includes the sign =

Any Idea ?

Comment: When i insert the invalid key hash displayed by the facebook error message in the facebook field for the hash key it works. But how can i get it ???

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias <RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS> -keystore <RELEASE_KEY_PATH> | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

Comment: I did it. Same bad result. The only difference with the command i did was the absence of parameter -list. Thank you. Jas

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this.

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```